# jQuery - Taking user input and inserting it into a multiple divs that have a class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to use jQuery to take the user input and insert it into multiple divs with the class of userInput.  I was able to use vanilla JavaScript but i don't want to keep repeating my code using ID's.

So far i can take the user input and display it as an alert so i know its being read. So can i take this input from the input field and place it into a class?

```
<form>
    <input class="userInput" type="text" maxlength="10" onclick="insertInput()" placeholder="Username" required><br>
    <a href="#chapter-1">
        <div id="submitbutton" class="button">Continue</div>
    </a>
</form>


$(function() {
    $("#submitbutton").click(function() {
        alert($(".userInput").val());
    });
});
```

Comment: <p class="userInput"> </p>

<p class="userInput"> </p>

<p class="userInput"> </p>



The p tag that the users input will be stored in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(function() {
  $("#submitbutton").click(function() {
    $('.userInput').text($(".userInput").val());
  });
});
```

check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Venugopal/o2gxgz9r/3552/)

Comment: Thank you so much ahhh so you use the .text :) Thank you so much this makes a lot more sense now :)

Answer (score 0):

Define number of `divs` having same class.Then just set the `input` value to class as `text`.

```js
$(function() {
                $("#submitbutton").click(function() {
                        var value = $(".userInput").val();
                        $(".insert").text(value);
                });
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
<input class="userInput" type="text" maxlength="10" placeholder="Username"  required><br>
<a href="#chapter-1">
<div id="submitbutton" class="button"> Continue</div>
</a>
</form>
<div class="insert">

</div>
<div class="insert">

</div>
<div class="insert">

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like so:

```js
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('p.userInput');

var doAction = function(event) {
  var inputValue = document.querySelector('input.userInput').value;
  
  for(var i=0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    elements[i].innerHTML = inputValue;
  }
}

var element = document.querySelector('#submitbutton');
element.addEventListener('click', doAction);
```

```html
<form>
  <input class="userInput" type="text" maxlength="10"  placeholder="Username"  required><br>
  <a href="#chapter-1">
    <div id="submitbutton" class="button"> Continue</div>
  </a>
</form>

<p class="userInput"> </p>
<p class="userInput"> </p>
<p class="userInput"> </p>
```

No reason to use jQuery.

Comment: Well i've already used jQuery for the rest of my project so it makes sense just to keep it in jQuery. Thank you though